# How to use multiple patterns within one regex object?

Tags: regex, vba, excel, web-scraping

I've written a script in `vba` in combination with `regular expressions` to parse `company name`, `phone` and `fax` from a webpage. when I run my script I get those information flawlessly. However, the thing is I've used three different `expressions` and to make them go successfully I created three different `regex objects`, as in `rxp`,`rxp1`, and `rxp2`.

My question: how can I create one `regex object` within which I will be able to use three `patterns` unlike what I've done below?

This is the script (working one):

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736"
    Dim rxp As New RegExp, rxp1 As New RegExp, rxp2 As New RegExp

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send

        rxp.Pattern = "Company Name:(\s[\w\s]+)"
        rxp1.Pattern = "Phone:(\s\+[\d\s]+)"
        rxp2.Pattern = "Fax:(\s\+[\d\s]+)"

        If rxp.Execute(.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [A1] = rxp.Execute(.responseText).Item(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        If rxp1.Execute(.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [B1] = rxp1.Execute(.responseText).Item(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        If rxp2.Execute(.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [C1] = rxp2.Execute(.responseText).Item(0).SubMatches(0)
         End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
```

Comment: Providing some sample data will get you better answers. Without seeing the layout we're just guessing how to combine the patterns.

Comment: There is already a link provided within the script @emsimpson92.

Comment: Have you tried OR regex sytax to combine into one pattern string ? Company Name:(\s[\w\s]+)|Phone:(\s\+[\d\s]+)|Fax:(\s\+[\d\s]+)  as your pattern ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @QHarr. I know how to combine them in a single pattern. What will be the use case? Once again, pattern is not the concern here. How can i use them to get three different results within a single regex object is what my question was. Thanks.

Comment: They would be in a single regex object.

Comment: If I use them as OR I get a single regex object which has 5 matches within. 4 numbers and one name. I guess I am misunderstanding what you mean by regex object. I guess you are after the groupings (As per given answer) which you can then pull groups from to populate your cells.

Comment: Declaring `rxp`, `rxp1` and `rxp2` As New RegExp is what I meant by regex object @QHarr. Probably there are accurate names to address them but I can't recall.

Comment: Ok. With OR you only needed to declare once. Or is part of what Wiktor has done. Another interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may build a regex with alternatives, enable global matching with `rxp.Global = True`, and capture the known strings into Group 1 and those unknown parts into Group 2. Then, you will be able to assign the right values to your variables by checking the value of Group 1:

```
Const Url$ = "https://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736"
Dim rxp As New RegExp
Dim ms As MatchCollection
Dim m As Match
Dim cname As String, phone As String, fax As String

With New XMLHTTP60
    .Open "GET", Url, False
    .send

    rxp.Pattern = "(Phone|Company Name|Fax):\s*(\+?[\w\s]*\w)"
    rxp.Global = True

    Set ms = rxp.Execute(.responseText)
    For Each m In ms
        If m.SubMatches(0) = "Company Name" Then cname = m.SubMatches(1)
        If m.SubMatches(0) = "Phone" Then phone = m.SubMatches(1)
        If m.SubMatches(0) = "Fax" Then fax = m.SubMatches(1)
    Next

    Debug.Print cname, phone, fax
End With
```

Output:

```
Vaucraft Braford Stud       +61 7 4942 4859              +61 7 4942 0618
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AE4nyl/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `(Phone|Company Name|Fax)` - Capturing group 1: any of the three alternatives
- `:\s*` - a colon and then 0+ whitespaces
- `(\+?[\w\s]*\w)` - Capturing group 2:

  - `\+?` - an optional `+`
  - `[\w\s]*` - 0 or more letters, digits, `_` or whitespaces
  - `\w` - a single letter, digit or `_`.

Comment: When there is any regex related issues, you are second to none @Wiktor Stribiżew. Thanksssss a trillion. One little question: why the submatches becomes 1 instead of 0? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @Topto The first capturing group - `.SubMatches(0)` - holds the known value by which we identify the type of the string we matched. The value we want to know is in Group 2, `.SubMatches(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Company Name:\s*(.*)\n?Phone:\s*(.*)\n?Fax:\s*(.*)\n?` will capture it into three capture groups. You can see how it works [here.](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/6)

Group 1 is your company name, group 2 is your phone number, and group 3 is your fax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but I'm not sure if that could be a good idea. Merging the regexp will make it more prone to problems/errors.

If you match all 3 data at the same time, all of them **must** be present or the regexp will fail. Or even worse, it will fetch wrong data. What happens if the fax is an optional field? See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Lo0pcP/2/) for examples.

Also, if the template of the web changes, it will be easier to break things. Let's say the template changes and the fax is rendered before the telephone: the whole regexp will fail because searching the 3 data at once means implying some order.

Unless the data you are searching is related or depends within each other, I wouldn't go to that route.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following can help do the same declaring `rxp` once:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, rxp As New RegExp

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
    End With

    With rxp
        .Pattern = "Company Name:(\s[\w\s]+)"
        If .Execute(Http.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [A1] = .Execute(Http.responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "Phone:(\s\+[\d\s]+)"
        If .Execute(Http.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [B1] = .Execute(Http.responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If

        .Pattern = "Fax:(\s\+[\d\s]+)"
        If .Execute(Http.responseText).Count > 0 Then
            [C1] = .Execute(Http.responseText)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```